# How to auto increment iOS notification badge with Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

How can I auto increment the iOS notification badge with Firebase Cloud Messaging? Is it possible to do something like `+1` or `++`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support for the documentation scroll down to **Table 2a. iOS — keys for notification messages** : badge Optional, string Indicates the badge on the client app home icon.

Comment: Note: this question shouldn't be marked as a duplicate. Firebase Cloud Messaging has a different API on top of APN so the answers to those other questions are not helpful and do not apply.

Comment: I just voted it for reopen as this is not a duplicate as Firebase Cloud Messaging has a different API.

Comment: This question should be reopened as the answers provided are not for the FCM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set badge value in ([notification payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)). You can use your own server to send push notifications and control (increment) a badge value. There is no way to control badge number if you are sending a push notification directly from device to device with Firebase. The only way you can set a badge is when you are sure the destination device will receive only push notifications from one source device, and you can set a badge value on that source device.

Comment: How does this solution solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682661/flutter-how-to-update-notification-badge-when-sending-notification-in-terminat?noredirect=1#comment124959421_70682661